# Wrong extra spaces for CID TrueType formated lines when converting PDF to JPG with Ghostscript

Tags: formatting, ghostscript, truetype, pdf-conversion

I am trying to convert a pdf document to a jpg using Ghostscript.
The following fonts are used in the original PDF file:

| name | type | emb | sub | uni | prob | object ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arial | TrueType | no | no | no | 3 | 0 |
| AOQTTQ+Arial,Bold-Identity-H | CID TrueType | yes | yes | yes | 5 | 0 |
| BGJLED+CourierNew-Identity-H | CID TrueType | yes | yes | yes | 10 | 0 |

The resulting document incorrectly contains additional spaces next to all characters in all words formatted with CourierNew CID TrueType.

I run the command and get the output as follows:

```
gswin32c -dBATCH c:\TEMP\test.pdf
GPL Ghostscript 9.56.1 (2022-04-04)
Copyright (C) 2022 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
Loading font Arial (or substitute) from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
```

After that the Ghostscript image window appears, where all lines formatted with CourierNew CID TrueType appear with extra spaces and the entire text is wider than the space provided for it. The rest of the document is formatted correctly.

The current version Ghostscript 10.02.1 also shows the same problem.

Comment: I doubt the problem is CouierNew. You are using a substitute font (Courier) to replace the CIDFont Arial, so yeah the metrics are different. If you don't want that that to happen then you should embed the font. You should **always** embed CIDFonts anyway. You can define the font that Ghostscript uses to replace Arial by editing fontmap.GS (for Fonts) and cidfmap (for CIDFonts). I expect if you define a reasonable substitute for Arial your problem will go away. See the documentation: https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html#explicit-cidfont-substitution

Comment: Oh, and you need to upgrade your version of Ghostscript. 9.56 is nearly 2 years old.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you give a more detailed explanation?
I have added the following line to the file ..\Resource\Init\cidfmap:

/Arial << /FileType /TrueType /Path (c:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
but nothing has changed.
How can I modify the file fontmap.GS to replace Arial?

Comment: Since this is a Font, not a CIDFont (going by your table above and assuming Arial is the problem) editing cidfmap won't help you as its not a CIDFont. You need to edit fontmap.GS. Also, since you are on Windows, you will need to tell Ghostscript to use the resources on disk instead of the ROM file system. If you don't specify -I/path to Resoruce/Init) then nothing will happen. You can read fontmap.GS for instructions on its format. You can also try specifying -sFONTPATH=